# Dynamically select which table to insert data into with entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

So I am writing an application which need to select an entity at run time and add through the entity framework save this to a database, I have created the database and a model based off it through the use of an ADO.NET Entity Data model, the objects, which hold the data are chosen baised on the data that is being added at runtime with the use of the reflection class, as follows;

```
                mytype = Type.GetType(objName);
                myObject = Activator.CreateInstance(mytype);
```

How can I do something like this to select the entity to use, is can i do something like this:

```
                db.[MyEntity].Add(myObject);
                db.SaveChanges();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get [DbSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset(v=vs.103)) by entity type:

```
var set = db.Set(myObject.GetType());
set.Add(myObject);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I tried the code and its working great

Answer (score 1):

You can use generic [Set](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696521%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) and create a generic method.

```
public static class MyLibrary
{
    public static void Add<T>(this DbContext db, T obj) where T : class
    {
        db.Set<T>().Add(obj);
    }
}
```

Usage.

```
db.Add(myObject);
```