# Dynamic models Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-6

I'm currently working on a generic function for inserting data tables via entity framework. However, with my current solution I ended up with a ton of very repetitive code with only a few minor differences. I would like to simplify what I have and remove the need for large case statements based on my table names (I only included two cases in this example to save space).

Here is what I currently have:

```
public static void InsertByTable(IEnumerable<DataTable> chunkedTable, string tableName)
    {
        switch (tableName)
        {
            #region Parcel
            case TaxDataConstant.Parcel:
                Parallel.ForEach(
                    chunkedTable,
                    new ParallelOptions
                    {
                        MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MaxThreads"])
                    },
                    chunk =>
                    {
                        Realty_Records_ProdEntities entities = null;
                        try
                        {
                            entities = new Realty_Records_ProdEntities();
                            entities.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;

                            foreach (DataRow dr in chunk.Rows)
                            {
                                var parcelToInsert = new Parcel();

                                foreach (DataColumn c in dr.Table.Columns)
                                {
                                    SetProperty(parcelToInsert, c.ColumnName, dr[c.ColumnName]);
                                }
                                entities.Parcels.Add(parcelToInsert);
                            }
                            entities.SaveChanges();
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            TaxDataError.AddTaxApplicationLog(
                                TaxDataConstant.CategoryError,
                                ex.Source,
                                ex.Message,
                                ex.StackTrace);
                            throw;
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            entities?.Dispose();
                        }
                    });
                break;
                #endregion

            #region Asmt
            case TaxDataConstant.Asmt:
                Parallel.ForEach(
                    chunkedTable,
                    new ParallelOptions
                    {
                        MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MaxThreads"])
                    },
                    chunk =>
                    {
                        Realty_Records_ProdEntities entities = null;
                        try
                        {
                            entities = new Realty_Records_ProdEntities();
                            entities.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;

                            foreach (DataRow dr in chunk.Rows)
                            {
                                var asmtToInsert = new Asmt();
                                foreach (DataColumn c in dr.Table.Columns)
                                {
                                    SetProperty(asmtToInsert, c.ColumnName, dr[c.ColumnName]);
                                }
                                entities.Asmts.Add(asmtToInsert);
                            }
                            entities.SaveChanges();
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            TaxDataError.AddTaxApplicationLog(
                                TaxDataConstant.CategoryError,
                                ex.Source,
                                ex.Message,
                                ex.StackTrace);
                            throw;
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            entities?.Dispose();
                        }
                    });
                break;
                #endregion
        }
    }
```

Is there any way I can make this table agnostic?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably move the logic in the case statement to a helper extension method which is generic. something like this (untested) pseudo code:

```
public static class EntityAdder
{
    public static void AddEntities<T>(this IEnumerable<DataTable> chunkedEntities, Action<Realty_Records_ProdEntities, T entity> addingFunction)
    {
        Parallel.ForEach(
            chunkedTable,
            new ParallelOptions
            {
                MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MaxThreads"])
            },
            chunk =>
            {
                Realty_Records_ProdEntities entities = null;
                try
                {
                    entities = new Realty_Records_ProdEntities();
                    entities.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;

                    foreach (DataRow dr in chunk.Rows)
                    {
                        var toInsert = new T();

                        foreach (DataColumn c in dr.Table.Columns)
                        {
                            SetProperty(parcelToInsert, c.ColumnName, dr[c.ColumnName]);
                        }
                        addingFunction(entities,toInsert);
                    }
                    entities.SaveChanges();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    TaxDataError.AddTaxApplicationLog(
                        TaxDataConstant.CategoryError,
                        ex.Source,
                        ex.Message,
                        ex.StackTrace);
                    throw;
                }
                finally
                {
                    entities?.Dispose();
                }
            });
    }
}
```

this could then be used something like this:

```
public static void InsertByTable(IEnumerable<DataTable> chunkedTable, string tableName)
{
    switch (tableName)
    {
        #region Parcel
        case TaxDataConstant.Parcel:
            chunkedTable.AddEntities((entities,newEntity)=> entities.Parcels.Add(newEntity))
            break;
            #endregion

        #region Asmt
        case TaxDataConstant.Asmt:
            chunkedTable.AddEntities((entities,newEntity)=> entities.Asmts.Add(newEntity))                
            break;
            #endregion
    }
}
```

you might be able to automate the adding bit by finding the property on the class which is a list of the things you want to add and avoid passing the action in if you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Sams response and some further [research](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25263469/dynamically-select-which-table-to-insert-data-into-with-entity-framework) I was able to refactor out the case statement.

Here's my solution:

```
public static void InsertByTable(IEnumerable<DataTable> chunkedTable, Type type)
    {
        Parallel.ForEach(
            chunkedTable,
            new ParallelOptions
            {
                MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MaxThreads"])
            },
            chunk =>
            {
                Realty_Records_ProdEntities entities = null;
                try
                {
                    entities = new Realty_Records_ProdEntities();
                    entities.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
                    var set = entities.Set(type);

                    foreach (DataRow dr in chunk.Rows)
                    {
                        var objectToInsert = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

                        foreach (DataColumn c in dr.Table.Columns)
                        {
                            SetProperty(objectToInsert, c.ColumnName, dr[c.ColumnName]);
                        }
                        set.Add(objectToInsert);
                    }
                    entities.SaveChanges();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    TaxDataError.AddTaxApplicationLog(
                        TaxDataConstant.CategoryError,
                        ex.Source,
                        ex.Message,
                        ex.StackTrace);
                    throw;
                }
                finally
                {
                    entities?.Dispose();
                }
            });
    }
```